# Data acquisition using DSO 2150 (Hantek, Virtins, etc.) in Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, data-transfer, signal

I have Virtins 2815H which is a DSO based on DSO 2150, I would like to real time record a signal around 1 MHz using it and process it in Raspberry Pi.

I have searched a lot about the data comm from it for data acquiring, but there is only written in C++ and ready made app that used for oscilloscope. I have tried to read the incoming USB data using [pyUSB](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb), no incoming data because the device needs to be activated first using a specific command from a PC. and I have tried to "sniff" the data transfer via USB from the device, but I cannot analyze it.

Has anyone tried the device using a Raspberry?

Comment: your question has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi .... does Virtins offer any linux software?